# Changing text values on labels and buttons

Tags: mono, gtk#

I hope this is a simple question, I'm new at Mono, and I'm having trouble getting to grips with GTK#'s bindings.

Essentially, I want to be able to programmatically change attributes against objects like labels, buttons and lists added in by the designer in MonoDevelop.

I know this can be done by instantiating a new instance of say, a button as such:

```
Button button1 = new Button("Text for button here");
```

However, say button1 was already created, how would I grab button1 to make changes to it?

Sorry if this all comes across a little thick, I'm still getting the hang of OOP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually easy enough, now I've sat and worked it out:

```
protected void OnButton1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button theButton = (Button)button1;
        theButton.Label = "New label text!!";
    }
```